# This GUI calculator doesn't work. What is wrong

Tags: java

I am trying to create a calculator With a GUI interface. The code below is meant to do this but only creates a blank space where you can type. What is wrong with it?

```
    public class CalculatorMain extends Calculator_ui
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          Calculator_ui n=new Calculator_ui();
          n.ui();

       }//main
    }//class
```

From this point is a new Java class

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    public class Calculator_ui implements ActionListener
    {
       JFrame frame=new JFrame("Calculator");
       JPanel panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

       JTextArea text=new JTextArea(5,20);

       JButton but1=new JButton("1");
       JButton but2=new JButton("2");
       JButton but3=new JButton("3");
       JButton but4=new JButton("4");
       JButton but5=new JButton("5");
       JButton but6=new JButton("6");
       JButton but7=new JButton("7");
       JButton but8=new JButton("8");
       JButton but9=new JButton("9");
       JButton but0=new JButton("0");

       JButton butadd=new JButton("+");
       JButton butsub=new JButton("-");
       JButton butmulti=new JButton("*");
       JButton butdiv=new JButton("/");
       JButton buteq=new JButton("=");

       JButton butclear=new JButton("C");

       Double number1,number2,result;
       int addc=0,subc=0,multic=0,divc=0;

       public void ui()
       {
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setSize(250,200);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          frame.add(panel);

          frame.add(text);

          panel.add(but1);
          panel.add(but2);
          panel.add(but3);
          panel.add(but4);
          panel.add(but5);
          panel.add(but6);
          panel.add(but7);
          panel.add(but8);
          panel.add(but9);
          panel.add(but0);

          panel.add(butadd);
          panel.add(butsub);
          panel.add(butmulti);
          panel.add(butdiv);
          panel.add(buteq);
          panel.add(butclear);

          but1.addActionListener(this);
          but2.addActionListener(this);
          but3.addActionListener(this);
          but4.addActionListener(this);
          but5.addActionListener(this);
          but6.addActionListener(this);
          but7.addActionListener(this);
          but8.addActionListener(this);
          but9.addActionListener(this);
          but0.addActionListener(this);
          butadd.addActionListener(this);
          butsub.addActionListener(this);
          butmulti.addActionListener(this);
          butdiv.addActionListener(this);
          buteq.addActionListener(this);
          butclear.addActionListener(this);



       }
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
          Object source=e.getSource();

          if(source==butclear)
          {
             number1=0.0;
             number2=0.0;
             text.setText("");
          }
          if(source==but1)
          {
             text.append("1");
          }
          if(source==but2)
          {
             text.append("2");
          }
          if(source==but3)
          {
             text.append("3");
          }
          if(source==but4)
          {
             text.append("4");
          }
          if(source==but5)
          {
             text.append("5");
          }
          if(source==but6)
          {
             text.append("6");
          }
          if(source==but7)
          {
             text.append("7");
          }
          if(source==but8)
          {
             text.append("8");
          }
          if(source==but9)
          {
             text.append("9");
          }
          if(source==but0)
          {
             text.append("0");
          }
          if(source==butadd)
          {
             number1=number_reader();
             text.setText("");
             addc=1;
             subc=0;
             multic=0;
             divc=0;
          }
          if(source==butsub)
          {
             number1=number_reader();
             text.setText("");
             addc=0;
             subc=1;
             multic=0;
             divc=0;
          }
          if(source==butmulti)
          {
             number1=number_reader();
             text.setText("");
             addc=0;
             subc=0;
             multic=1;
             divc=0;
          }
          if(source==butdiv)
          {
             number1=number_reader();
             text.setText("");
             addc=0;
             subc=0;
             multic=0;
             divc=1;
          }
          if(source==buteq)
          {
             number2=number_reader();
             if(addc>0)
             {
                result=number1+number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
             }
             if(subc>0)
             {
                result=number1-number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
             }
             if(multic>0)
             {
                result=number1*number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
             }
             if(divc>0)
             {
                result=number1/number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
             }
          }
       }

       public double number_reader()
       {
          Double num1;
          String s;
          s=text.getText();
          num1=Double.valueOf(s);

          return num1;
       }




       public static void main(String[] args)
       {

       }//main
    }//class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
frame.add(text);
```

by

```
panel.add(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not making any `text.setText(<value>);` in your code. I'm not sure that the `append` function is working as wish to.

Comment: He call text.setText() and text.append() and append does exactly what is normal to do append the text to the end of the text it already have, why you said that he didn't?

Comment: Ok,  knowledge transfered!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using JFrame default layout that is a BorderLayout to add the panel and the text, and by default it add the components to the center (so they hide the others if you add more than one), you can add one in the top and one in the center with:

```
  frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  frame.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You can see what layouts exists in [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). And of course see the oracle official tutorials about GUI in [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Also, your buttons are put in a flow layout so they will be one after another. Maybe you can use a [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to positioning it as a real calculator.

And you don't need to add a main method to all classes if they won't be executed.